# How can I do function return code for country name on angular 7?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face Issue : I can't do function return country code for country name .

I already have ZCO as country name input but my issue :

How to return country code from country name ?

Actually for More clear

I need function on angular 7 give it country name as ZCO and it return Country Code .

ZCO represent country name as

India , egypt,unitedstates

And it must return  country code from function get code as :

IN,EG,US

ON ts compoent:

```
 this.OriginCountry= this.partDetailsService.currentData.OriginCountry;  
    this.OriginCountry.forEach(e => {  
              e.code=getCode(e.ZCO);  
      
            });
```

getcode take parameter ZCO as country name and return countrycode :

```
getCode(e.ZCO);
{
return code // as country code
}
```

How to make it as function get code

```
 getCode(e.ZCO);
    {
    return code // as country code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CountryCodeService` that will do the processing. You will have to create an internal map to associate country names with country codes:

```
interface Country {
    name: string;
    code: string;
}

const countryMap: Country[] = [
    // ...
    { name: "India", code: "IN" },
    // ...
]
```

This way you can retrieve a country by name with a `find` on the array and get the associated country code:

```
getCode(countryName: string): string {
    const country: Country | undefined = this.countryMap.find((c: Country) => c.name === countryName);
    if (!country) {
        throw new Error(`Could not find country code for country ${countryName}`);
    }

    return country.code;
}
```

Comment: this is good but how to do that on get code function

Comment: can you help me on that please

Comment: I need function and how to call